# Why un-moduled JAR can access non exposes packaged of a moduled JAR?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, module-info

I'm playing around with Java 9 in intelliJ:
I've created 4 modules (all modules depended on module1):

1. module1: exports packages pkg1 and exports pkg2 to module 2.
2. module2: requires module1 and able to access both packages
3. module3: requires module1 and able to access only pkg1
4. module4: does not have the module-info.class, able to access both packages of module1

I thought that automatic modules should require all exposed packaged but not the ones which are not exposed.

I don't understand what is the point of encapsulation, if it works only on explicitly moduled JARs.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

In your example *module4* will **not** be able to access `pkg2`. Automatic modules *read* all other modules (because they can not express dependencies), but the [rules to *access* types](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-module-system-tutorial/#exports-accessibility) are not changed, so only public types in exported packages are accessible.

Some background based on your quote:

> I thought that automatic modules should require all exposed packaged but not the ones which are not exposed.

Explicit modules (i.e. not automatic modules) *require* other modules. At run time those requires directives are [turned into *readability edges*](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-module-system-tutorial/#dependencies-readability). But they are not the only source for those edges: For automatic modules an edge is added to each module that was resolved (i.e. made it into the readability graph).

So when you say "automatic modules should require all exposed package[s]" there are a couple of mistakes, maybe lost in translation, but I still want to clarify. The sentence should instead say "automatic modules read all (resolved) modules".

At this stage nobody is talking about accessibility and packages yet. That's the next step and here automatic modules are not special, so they can not access internal APIs.

Comment: So according to theory module 4 should not be able to access package pkg2.
But it does compile, I've created those 4 modules in intelliJ and added a module dependency for module 4 to be depended on module 1, and I'm able to create a new instance of a class from pkg2.
I've also build a JAR from module 1 and tried to add dependency on the JAR in a new project and again I'm able to instantiate a class from pkg2.
The only scenario where I get a compiliation error is if I add a module-info.java file to my module then add a require statement for module1, only then compilation fails.

Comment: Modules are only created from JARs on the module path. If you compile a non-modular project, IntelliJ will likely put its dependencies on the class path (at least Maven does that), which means there never is a _module1_. Instead compiled code and all dependencies end up in the same unnamed module, within which no module boundaries exist.

Comment: To be backwards compatible, Java 9 does not change the behavior of code on the class path. The user must opt into the module system (at least for application modules) by putting JARs onto the module path.

Comment: @NicolaiParlog I went through your videos on youtube. I'm still facing this exact same issue. I created a project with two packages and exported only one of them. I generated a `.jar` file out of this project. Then I included this jar in another project via IntelliJ -> project structure -> module -> dependencies. Yet somehow I'm able to access the public class from unexposed package from the jar file. Only if I create a module-info.java file in the consumer project does it warn me about the non accessibility. I can't seem to understand why so? None of the answers below seem to clarify this.

Comment: @SalvinoD'sa An IntelliJ module isn't necessarily a Java module and without a module declaration in the consumer project, IntelliJ will (rightfully) place its dependencies on the class path. But modular JARs on the class path don't become a proper module, they end up in the unnamed module, which exports all packages. For a longer explanation see https://dev.java/learn/modules/unnamed-module/ (Sorry for the late answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Since the [automatic modules](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#automatic-modules) in the module system doesn't have a module descriptor(`module-info.class`), there is hence no good way to determine which other modules an automatic module might depend upon.

After a module graph is resolved, therefore, an automatic module is ***made to read every other named module, whether automatic or explicit.***

Hence in your case, `module4` being an automatic module is able to read the explicit module `module1`.

---

The [accessibility as defined in the module system](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#accessibility)(similarity drawn out by me) is illustrated as: If two types `S` and `T` are defined in different modules, and `T` is `public`, then code in `S` can access `T` if:

- **S’s module reads T’s module**, (`module4` reads `module1`) and
- **T’s module exports T’s package**. (`module1` exports `pckg1` to all modules that requires `module1` and `pckg2` to only `module2`)

---

> A type referenced across module boundaries that is not accessible in
>   this way is unusable in the same way that a private method or field is
>   unusable: Any attempt to use it will cause an error to be reported by
>   the compiler, or an `IllegalAccessError` to be thrown by the Java
>   virtual machine, or an `IllegalAccessException` to be thrown by the
>   reflective run-time APIs.
>
> Thus, *even when a type is declared public,
>   if its package is not exported in the declaration of its module then
>   it will only be accessible to code in that module*.

Comment: So that limits the encapsulation to only moduled JARs? I don't understand the logic of such a design. If my module decides to not expose a package why should it care if it is used by a moduled or not moduled JAR? If that really is the case, then this feature seems kind of broken to me(I understand that this was the case before modules also, but still).

Comment: @Nicolai Well, the question read being able to access both the packages. Agreed to the point that modules should be able to access the packages exported by the module they read.

Answer (score 0):

To Eliminate IntelliJ logic, I've built 3 JARs from my modules(1, 2 & 4) and started playing around with them using java in the command line.

When I tried to execute the code using only -cp option it had the same behavior of module4 being able to access pkg2 -> this brings me to the conclusion that if there is no module-info.java file in an IntelliJ module it uses the classpath.

Here is the tricky part:
I've used --list-modules option to ensure the automatic name for module4 is module4.
Then I've executed something like:

```
java -p "<module1 path>;<module4 path>" -m module4/<MainClass>
```

I've got a ClassNotFoundException on a class from pkg1 (the exported package).

if I execute:

```
java -p "<module1 path>;<module2 path>" -m module2/<MainClass>
```

then everything works.

So it seems like if we want to use the module path the main class must be from a moduled JAR.

Looks like, automatic JARs are for backward compatibility, so that we will be able to use them as dependencies of our new modules.

However if want to execute a module using the module path, Java assumes that the JAR we are executing is a moduled JAR, otherwise we should keep using the classpath.

In other words, if we execute an un-moduled JAR using the -p (modulepath) option it will not require other modules in the path.

All these conclusions came from playing around with the Java, can someone point me to the exact parts of theory behind it?